# preventDefault() not woking in Mozilla

Tags: jquery, preventdefault

I want to avoid entering hypen to be entered in text box. 
The text box field is for a phone number which is in US format, therefore i am adding -(dash) after 3rd and 6th digit through JQuery which is automatically adding as user enters, but i didn't want user to enter -(dash) manually through keyboard.

```
$("#someID").keydown(function (e){
if(e.keyCode==189){
    e.preventDefault();
}else{

    var myLength = $(this).val().length;
    var text1=$(this).val();
    if((myLength==3) ){              
        $(this).val($(this).val()+'-');
              }else if(myLength==7){
                  $(this).val($(this).val()+'-');
              }
    }  
});
```

189 is keycode for -(dash/hyphen)

Comment: The code works for me ... what is your specific problem?

Comment: Do you have the latest jQuery?

Comment: At least in my Firefox (Mac OS X), the key code for dash is 173... just to tell you *why* it does not work.

Comment: In my computer/keyboard/Firefox, codes for dash are 173 (regular) and 109 (numeric keypad). And the user can also paste a number from clipboard. It's probably better to capture the actual character being inserted.

Answer (score 2):

jQuery normalizes `which` property and you can use this property instead of `keyCode`:

```
if (e.which === 189) {
```

You can also consider using [Masked Input](http://digitalbush.com/projects/masked-input-plugin/) plugin.

Comment: Its Done!! I have to use e.which==189 for IE and e.which==173 for mozilla.

Answer (score 0):

just change to this:

```
if(e.keyCode==109){
   //---------^^^------109 is the keycode for hyphen
```

you can check here: http://www.cambiaresearch.com/articles/15/javascript-char-codes-key-codes